# Are elliptic Kummer extensions big?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

Loosely speaking, are elliptic Kummer extensions big?  More concretely:

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{Q}$, let $p$ be a prime, and
let $F$ be a subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ containing the
coordinates of all the $p$-power torsion of $E$.  Given $c > 0$, does
there
exist $N > 0$ (depending only on $E$, $F$, and $p$) such that:
If P is a point of $E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ whose image in
$(E(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})/E(F))$ has
order $p^n$ (in other words, $[p^n]P \in E(F)$, but this does not hold for
any smaller power of $p$) with $n \geq N$, then $[F(P):F] \geq c$?

Remarks:

- I am aware of some Theorems of Basmakov, Ribet, and Bertrand that are roughly in this direction, and in fact more general cases than elliptic curves are considered (e.g. Ribet's paper "Kummer theory on extensions of abelian varieties by tori" -- Duke Math J. 1979).  One shortcoming of these excellent papers is that the results are only for almost every prime.  I am very interested in the prime 2 (unfortunately!).
- $\operatorname{Gal}(F(P)/F)$ is naturally a subgroup of $E[p^n]$.
- The G_m analogue is easy -- the degree of a Kummer extension is as
  big as it could be.
- If it's easier, the most important case for me is when $E$
  has CM and $F$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}(E_{tors})$.
- Does the following make sense:  Given a point $Q \in E(F)$, there is a
  representation $G_F \to (\mathbb{Z}_p)^2$ and more generally $G_\mathbb{Q}
  \to (\mathbb{Z}_p)^2 \rtimes \operatorname{GL}_2(\mathbb{Z_p})$ coming
  from the Galois action on points $P$ satisfying $[p^n]P = Q, n \in
  \mathbb{N}$, and in this context what I'm asking is in the spirit of
  Serre's Theorem on the large image of the $p$-adic representation, but I'm asking the image to be large *uniformly in $Q$?*

Comment: What does $[p^{\infty}]$ mean in the formula $(E (\overline{\mathbb Q}/E(F))[p^{\infty}]$?

Comment: Will: I have deleted it.  I meant those elements of the quotient which have $p$-power order.  Of course this wasn't necessary to include.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$Gal(F(P)/F)$ is indeed a subgroup of $E[p^{n}]$. We see that it is not contained in $E[p^{n-1}]$, because otherwise $p^{n-1}P\in E(F)$. Thus, since $E[p^{n-1}]$ consists of all the elements of order less than $p^n$, order of $Gal(F(P)/F)$ is at least $p^N$. So we may take any $N \leq \log_p c$

Comment: I agree with your argument, but (both in the question and the answer) I think that the inclusion $\mathrm{Gal}(F(P)/F)\hookrightarrow E[p^n]$ is not natural: it should be the map $\sigma\mapsto P^\sigma-P$, which depends on $P$, unlike $F(P)$. Also, your argument works with this choice and not with other abstract ones, I think - or I do not see how to deduce that the image is not contained in $E[p^{n-1}$.

Comment: It is natural because the $p^N$ torsion of $E$ is defined over $F$. Otherwise you would just obtain a class in $ H^1(F,E[p^N])$

Comment: But what is the map exactly? Isn't it the one I wrote down?

Comment: Yes. That map only depends on $P$ up to elements of $E[F]$. Since $E[p^n]$ is contained in $E[F]$, the map is a well-defined homomorphism. Otherwise, it would just be a cocycle, well-defined up to a coboundary.

Comment: I agree with what you write, simply in the question there is only the assumption that $E[p]$ be contained in $F$, not the whole $E[p^n]$. Anyhow I am sorry for the pedantic discussion, it is getting longer than it would deserve...

Comment: It says $p$-power torsion in the question, not $p$-torsion. $p$-power torsion includes $p^n$ torsion for all $n$. It's fine!

Comment: Thanks, @Will.  Here is how I am understanding the argument:
If you look at the sum $S$ of $P - P^\sigma$ over all elements $\sigma$ of $\operatorname{Gal}(F(P)/F)$, then of course $S$ belongs to $E(F)$ because it is a sum of $p^n$-torsion points.  On the other hand, if this Galois group has size $M$, then $S$ differs from $[M]P$ by an element of $E(F)$, so $[M]P \in E(F)$, and hence the order of $P$ in the quotient is at most $M$.

It seems what I asked was too weak.  The more difficult question would be to show that $[F(P):F]$ is only less than the size of $E[p^n]$ by a bounded amount.

Comment: Your understanding seems like a correct way to view my argument, but I think that more difficult question is false. I believe there are usually infinitely many $n$ such that $[F(P):F] =p^n$, whereas the size of $E[p^n]$ is of course $p^{2n}$.

Comment: @Will, Can you explain why you believe this?

Comment: Sorry, my perspective on it was not so good. Actually, I think it depends a lot on the field $F$. In particular, take a field $F$ and a sequence of points $P_1,P_2,P_3$ such that $p^n P_n \in E[F]$, but $p^{n-1} P_n \not\in E[F]$. Then you can adjoin some elements to $F$ to make $Gal(F(P_n)|F) = \mathbb Z/p^n$, which makes the degree $p^n$ but keeps $p^{n-1} P_N \not\in E[F]$. There is no reason that doing this for one $P_n$ would mess up the other $P_n$s, so we can do this for each $P_n$ individually.